# Find command iteration through years and month

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nested-loops

i need your help on this please

I have an enormous directory with millions and millions of files and im trying to group those by year and month using the find command and then tar it to save some space.

I have created a bash script like the following

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/data/historical

/usr/bin/cd  /data/backupfile

sleep 2

[ -e "$DIR" ] || mkdir "$DIR"

sleep 2


for year in 2019 2020 2021 2022
do 
    for month in jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sept oct nov dec
    do 
        mkdir -p /data/historical/"$year"/"$month" 
    done
            
    for prev feb mar apr may jun jul aug sept oct nov dec jan 
    do 
        /usr/bin/find ! -newermt "$prev 31 $year"  -newermt  "$month 1 $year"  -exec mv {} /data/historical/"$month" \;
    done
            
done
```

## Also tried this way

```
years=2019,2020,2021,2022
months=01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

#months=`date '+%b'`
#after=`date -d '1 month' '+%b'`

for year in $(echo ${years})
do
    for month in "${months[@]}"
    do
        
        /usr/bin/find ! -newermt "$year-$month-31" -newermt "$year-$month-01" -exec mv {} /data/historical/"$month" \;
    done
done
```

So, this what i really need. I need to iterate through every year (2019 2020 2021 2022) starting with 2019 and every month ( 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12) starting with 01 ... 12, get the files grouped by month-year and then tar it and them keep iterating through the other year ie 2020.

For example:

/usr/bin/find ! -newermt "feb 29 2019" -newermt "jan 1 2019" -exec mv {} /data/historical/2019 ; && /usr/bin/tar -czf /data/historical/file.tar.gz /data/historical/2019

I have tried change the variables, playing with the iteration and for loops, nested for loops. The directories 2019/{jan...dec} are created but the files i want to search for and grouped by month and year are not there.

#EDIT

To help you understand better:

My enormous file is /data/backupfile

It contains files from 2019-2022

I want to group those files by year/month that's why Im trying to create directories 2019/Jan and get those jan-2019, feb-2019, etc files from /data/backupfile.

I've been trying to do that using nested loops. Maybe there's a better solution?

Comment: The files that I want to move are on another directory, so I'm creating a new directory to move those files. I'm want to create several directories 2019/{Jan...Dec} with all the files belonging to that date 2019-jan. Hope this helps to clarify

Comment: Do `/data/backupfile` contain any subdirectories or are all its contents regular files? And `/data/backupfile` **is a directory**, right?

Comment: I suggest that you turn the variables `years` and `months` into arrays. There are more problems with your script, but this would be a start.

Comment: Yes it is a directory @oguzismail , and all of the contents are regular files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU findutils installed this should work fine:

```
cd /data/backupfile
find -type f -printf '%p/%TY/%Tb\0' |
  xargs -0 sh -c '
for args; do
  src=${args%/*/*}
  dst=/data/historical${args#"$src"}
  echo mkdir -p "$dst" &&
    echo mv "$src" "$dst"
done' sh
```

Remove both `echo`s if you're happy with the output.